# Что в телефонах отсчитывает время? Что является его эталоном времени?

Tags: java, android, время

Устал гуглить..что за контроллер времени импользуется в современных смартфонах и что является его эталоном времени? В каком виде этот контроллер представляет информацию установленной операционной системе?

Comment: телефоны могут брать время из сети, из GPS и из внутренних часов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В смартфоне стоит *кварцевый резонатор* и микросхемка-счётчик. Точность встроенного кварца вполне приемлема для обычного пользователя, особенно если телефон новый. Со временем из-за "усталости" кристалла частота начинает "уходить" и часы врут всё больше и больше. Таким образом, встроенный кварц и является эталоном времени для смартфона в режиме оффлайн.

Ясно, что кварц имеет намного меньшую точность, чем атомные эталоны, поэтому в режиме онлайн смартфон синхронизирует свои внутренние часы с внешними эталонами времени. Обычно используется *NTP* - при подключении к Интернет смартфон обращается к серверам точного времени и синхронизируется с ними. Более продвинутые модели для синхронизации могут использовать сигналы *GPS/ГЛОНАСС* или сети *GSM*.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что для синхронизации по GPS не нужен интернет, а по сети GSM - нужна только сим-карта и насчет продвинутости моделей несколько сомнительно - сколько себя помню в настройках android всегда был пункт "Получать время\часовой пояс из сети" - это как раз от вышки GSM

Comment: Значит алгоритм такой: в микросхеме есть память которая по дефолту имеет дату 1970 года, мы при включении устанавливаем время,  далее микросхема отсчитывает время и говорит от 1970 года прошло столько то наносекунд. Время от времени оно синхронизируется с точным числом наносекунд от 1970 года.  Ну это для Unix систем такой отсчет времени в наносекундах от 1970 года.  Ну и остается вопрос, что есть эталон сеунды в кварцевом резонаторе?  Ну это я думаю сейчас смогу нагуглить

Comment: @pavlofff Насколько мне известно, это как раз не GSM, а NTP. Впрочем, может быть, я и ошибаюсь.

Comment: @kff эта настройка ставит время и без доступа к интернету, и  при недавних экспериментах с часовыми поясами, на МТС у меня с полгода время из сети было на час разницы с реальным, а на мегафоне правильное.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, RTC уже давно встроенный, и питается от общей батареи. Операционка после запуска получает текущее время по NTP.

Comment: Думаю не от общей батареи,  т.к. при ее извлечении часы продолжают работать. Только в очень бюджетных телефонах, время приходится ставить по новой. Операционка думаю так быстро не синхронизируется по NTP. Ну не в этом суть.